# Digital Ocean : Out of memory error when running nginx react and node with docker

Tags: node.js, docker, express, nginx

I am using the 5 dollar digital ocean plan to host mongodb, nginx, react node through docker and docker compose. The problem I have is that it keeps giving me

```
The build failed because the process exited too early. This probably means the system ran out of memory or someone called `kill -9` on the process.
```

This image building starts with the backend and then react where this error occurs. The specific line it occurs is at

```
Step 5/9 : RUN yarn build
 ---> Running in e12af022dcf1
yarn run v1.22.5
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
```

I am using the multi-stage docker build for react and nginx

```
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /usr/app
COPY ./client .
RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

FROM nginx:alpine
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY --from=build /usr/app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: Try it with a bigger droplet or run it locally while monitoring memory consumption.

Comment: it works locally. How do you monitor memory consumption?

Comment: with `top` or for containers specifically, you can try https://github.com/bcicen/ctop

Answer (score 0):

Building docker images directly on the droplet is not a good idea, here is how I solved it:

- Build the docker image on my machine
- Upload it to their docker registry (using their `doctl` tool)
- Pull the image from within the droplet and run it (using their `doctl` tool)